# send this spark streaming dataframe to hbase using scala

Tags: scala, hbase, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am receiving kafka in spark streaming and processing my data to create dataframe which looks like this :

```
+---+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |sen                      |attributes                                                                                                                                                    |
+---+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |Stanford is good college.|[[Stanford,ORGANIZATION,NNP], [is,O,VBZ], [good,O,JJ], [college,O,NN], [.,O,.], [Stanford,ORGANIZATION,NNP], [is,O,VBZ], [good,O,JJ], [college,O,NN], [.,O,.]]|
+---+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have hbase table "kafkaStreaming" with columns id and att. I want this data to be saved in hbase with "ID" as row key and attributes for example [[Stanford,ORGANIZATION,NNP], [is,O,VBZ], [good,O,JJ]] in att.

I want to dynamically add column families whenever this data comes. Please help.

Comment: I want to know how do I convert it into PUT objects to inject them to HBASE

Answer (score -1):

We have example code for this at [Splice Machine](http://%20https://github.com/splicemachine/splice-community-sample-code.)

If you want to attempt to write the low level bits, you can dynamically create HBase Puts and run them through a function call or an OutputFormat.  The Put syntax allows as many column families as you would like.

Failure semantics tend to not be so hot under this approach.  How do you rollback failures etc?

Comment: Makes sense.  Our code is all in java (Not helpful).  Cloudera has some open source code located here https://github.com/cloudera-labs/SparkOnHBase.  They have some minimal scala code for interacting with Hbase.  Hope this helps.